# Form that submits to the same action, with an id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, routes

I'm trying to do something that seems very simple: create a form that submits to same URL it was requested from, with an id.

If I didn't care about the id, I could do:

```
<% using(Html.Form()) { %>
    <!-- stuff -->
<% } %>
```

But since I want the id, I have to use a different overload.

I would like something along the lines of:

```
<% using(Html.Form(some, args, new {id="myAwesomeForm"})) { %>
    <!-- stuff -->
<% } %>
```

I can't just hardcode the action and controller because the form is used in a couple of different places. Sometimes the URL will have parameters (`/items/edit/1`, and other times it will not `/items/create`)

There must be some incredibly simple way of doing this that is going to make me feel like an idiot when I see it. So, what is it?

---

**Clarification**: I mean an id on the HTML element, as in `<form action="/my/action[/possible arguments]" id="myAwesomeForm"></form>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use null for the action and controller; they will be filled in from the current action and controller.

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm( null, null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { id = 3 } )) { %>

 <% } %>
```

Comment: Sorry, I clarified my question. I mean an `id` the HTML attribute, not the route parameter. In my example above, what you've posted would result in `<form action="/my/action/3"></form>`, which is not what I want.

Comment: @notJim - oh, just use null for the route values as well and add the FormMethod to get the right signature.

Answer (score 0):

Just use the first overload (routeValues As Object)

It will assume the current, **Area Name**, **Controller Name** and **Action Name** parameters.  **Post** is the default form method.

```
<%
    Using Html.BeginForm(New With {.id = 3})

    End Using
%>
```

Comment: Check the clarification, I was looking for an HTML `id`, not an `id` in the route.

Comment: Oh ok.  You could always go old school and just write html... <for id="myAweseomForm" action="<%=Request.Url.PathAndQuery%>" method="post">... it's so 2001, but it might be easier to understand what your code is doing then the complicated HTML helper method.